# Entity Framework Core primary key

Tags: c#, sqlite, ef-core-2.1

In my commerce web app I have a table `OrderItem` where the primary key is set on sqlite is

```
<Id-productId-variant>
id is integer not null
productId is text not null
variant is text null
```

Variant is nullable because is refer to foreign key on Variant table where the variant column is not null but in my `orderItem` table I allow insert of products without variant

In sqlite the insert works well for both case: with and without variant.

EF Core instead returns an error when there is no variant

> Unable to track an entity of type 'OrderItem' because primary key property 'Variant' is null.

What can I do?

```
builder.HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.Codart, e.Codvar });
      ...

        builder
        .HasOne(e => e.Product)
        .WithOne(e => e.OrderItems)
        .HasForeignKey<OrderItems>(e => e.Codart);

        builder
        .HasOne(e => e.Variant)
        .WithOne(e => e.OrderItems)
        .HasForeignKey<OrderItems>(e => new { e.Codart, e.Codvar });


public class Variant
{
    [key]
    public string Codart { get; set; } 
    [key]
    public string Codvar { get; set; }
    public string Descri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't declare variant  as a nullable type in your model. 
string? Variant;

Comment: String is reference type so do not need to make nullable

Comment: Sorry, i meant the VariantId in OrderItem whatever its type is should be nullable. I'm just assuming so it would be helpful if you shared some code.

Comment: [Maybe this is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291466/entity-framework-core-nullable-foreign-key)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public class Variant
{

    public Variant() 
    {
       Codart = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       Codvar = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       // Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), that's for every Key non nullable
    }

    [key]
    public string Codart { get; set; }
    [key] 
    public string Codvar { get; set; }
    public string Descri { get; set; }
}
```