# EF Core: Optional one-to-one foreign key relation from content entity

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, ef-model-builder

I've implemented some database context for my .net core blazor application. 
The database context has access to an external database (no database migration etc.)

Now my problem is that I am not sure how to define a foreign key using fluent api or data attributes when the parent table contains the foreign key for the table.

As simplified example: I've got a transactions entity with data like this:

```
[Table("transactions")]
public class Transaction
{
  [Key]
  [Column("id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Column("trans_num")]
  public string TransNum { get; set; }

  [Column("shop_id")]
  public int? ShopId { get; set; }

  [Column("total_amount")]
  public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

  public Shop Shop { get; set;}
}
```

And some shop entity with data like this:

```
[Table("shops")]
public class Shop
{
  [Key]
  [Column("id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Column("shop_name")]
  public string ShopName{ get; set; }

  public Transaction Transaction { get; set;}
}
```

As the models indicate, the "shop_id" is the foreign key.

So ... I've got no transaction reference within my shop entity. Also, in my productive scenario I've got some optional relations like this, meaning for example shop_id would be null.

How would I indicate the optional relation to my model builder?

Best regards

Comment: is there one -one relationship or one-many relationship?

Comment: One-to-one relatioship. But it's optional, so one-to-none-or-one

Comment: this will help you to set  one-one or one-to-one-or-none relationship  
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-one-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this is the other way round ... which is why I am asking here. In the example you provided the StudentAddress entity contains the foreign key. Which would be normal ... but in this case I've got my transaction entity which I want to fetch and have the optional Shop information if the foreign key field within transactions is set.

I don't have a foreign key within my shop entity.

Comment: in that case, you relationship is maybe one-to-none-or-one-or-many. you can refer this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291466/entity-framework-core-nullable-foreign-key

Comment: It's clear, that my ShopId Property within my Transaction Model must be nullable. But still I don't know how to setup this relation within my model builder. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set optional FK  in model builder

```
[Table("shops")]
public class Shop
{
  [Key]
  [Column("id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Column("shop_name")]
  public string ShopName{ get; set; }

  public virual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set;}
}

     modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Transactions)
            .WithOptional(c => c.Shop)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ShopId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

if you are looking only for EF core then you can refer this link :

[WithOptional with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513232/withoptional-with-entity-framework-core)

Comment: I am able to receive the transaction using your solution but my navigational property on the transaction for the corresponding shop is null even though my foreign key is set to id "1".

Comment: Oh, nevermind, forgot to add the lazy loading proxies. It's working like a charm now. Thank you very much!